Применяются несуществующие стили к странице
Самая распространенная проблема - не применяются стили к шаблону. 
У меня же все наоборот: удаляя стили из файла, страница продолжает выглядеть так, будто бы стили существуют.
После перезагрузки, миграции базы данных - все так же.
Проблема исправляется при удалении шаблона и стилей и их дальнейшем добавлении заново в проект. Но спустя какое-то время все начинается сначала.
Кроме того, когда случается данный казус, я не могу добавить новые стили: шаблон не видит все стили, кроме тех, что были изначально.
Структура проекта:
languages
media
polyglot
polyglot_info
users
venv
db.sqlite3
manage.py


Чистить кэш браузера не забываете? Перезапускать collectstatic не забываете?

чищу, конечно, делал жесткую перезагрузку - все бесполезно

На 100%  уверен что стили грузятся не оттуда откуда вы думаете что они должны быть. Смотрите в браузере откуда они берутся

Вероятно браузер кеширует html ответы. Попробуйте Ctrl+F5 чтобы обновить страницу без кеша. Через инструменты разработчика в браузере можно посмотреть, откуда именно стили тянутся.

попробуйте в шаблоне в ручную прописать путь к статик файлам вставляя такую конструкцию в соответсвующих местах кода
"{% static /путь к файлу стилей.../" %}"


Автор не спрашивал, почему стилей нет, он спрашивал с точностью до наоборот, почему они есть, когда не должно быть.

как уже отметил выше Alexey Ten я тоже на 100% уверен что стили грузятся не оттуда откуда думает разработчик. Поэтому я подумал что проще всего вручную каркасно указать на стили.
